# ExpandableListView not working properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, expandablelistview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am implementing an app with `ExpandableListview`, `Fragment`, `Viewpager` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

But I have a problem. My `ExpandableListview` has a wrong behavior. The remaining items below are cut. And when I click on an item below the top item displayed behind TabLayout.

What is my error in the code? Thank you

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="30dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="25dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/HeaderTitleStyle"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/img_oficinas"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tabs_text_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: what type of error you are getting??

Comment: @Madhur The items below are cut off and the items above appear behind the Tablayout when the lower are clicked

Comment: set fixed height and width

Answer (score 0):

`CoordinatorLayout`'s *ScrollingViewBehavior* only works with views that support nested scrolling (exp `RecyclerView`). 
`ExpandableListView` does not support it by default, so the `CoordinatorLayout` is not handling the position of the `ExpandableListView` correctly.

For **API >21** you can obtain this behavior by:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {   
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

Otherwise you can switch to a custom `RecyclerView` or [ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view).